# Question mark( �) displaying instead of each Bengali unicode character. How to fix it?

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, special-characters

The problem is confusing,such as,

When I am trying to display a Bengali unicode word,'কলম' with this

```
 $data=$_POST['data'];
 echo $data;
```

Then it displays the word '**কলম**' properly as I wanted,

But when I split the word character by character with this

```
    for($i=0;$i<3;$i++)
    {
        echo $data[$i];         
        echo "+";
    }
```

Then it display '**�+�+�+**' instead of displaying like this 'ক+ল+ম+'.

How to solve this problem .Thank you.

For information ,  I have declared charset utf-8 in head.

> < meta http-equiv= " Content-Type " content= " text/html;
>   charset=utf-8 " />

Comment: If you see that character (� U+FFFD "REPLACEMENT CHARACTER") it usually means that the text itself is encoded in some form of single byte encoding but interpreted in one of the unicode encodings (UTF8 or UTF16).add

header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mb_substr($data, $i, 1)` instead. You are using a multi-byte string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this hope this will work

```
<?php
$data = $_POST['data'];
$strlen = mb_strlen( $data );
for( $i = 0; $i <= $strlen; $i++ ) {
    $char = mb_substr( $str, $i, 1 );
    echo $char;
    echo '+';
}
?>
```